# Issue with uploading sourcemaps with sentry-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, sentry

I have issue with sentry webpack plugin https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin... I have read manual and tried so many things, but can't figure out what's wrong... However, I'm using webpack 3... Every time I get this error

> ./node_modules/@sentry/cli/sentry-cli releases new 1520006165 error:
>   An organization slug is required (provide with --org)

but organization, project, token are provided to SentryCliPlugin by sentry.properties file that contains all required data...
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#configuration-via-properties-file

```
new SentryCliPlugin({
 release: process.env.LAST_BUILD_TIME,
 configFile: process.env.SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE,
 include: './app/dist'
})
```

sentry.properties file (added)

```
[defaults]
url=https://sentry.io/
org=<YourOrgShortname>
project=<YourProjectShortname>

[auth]
token=<YourToken>
```

Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

I've opened issue on github repo... 
It's package related problem.
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

Your linked documentation is wrong cause it's for the Java client instead of Java**script**. According to the exception, you're using TS/JS with JS. They're not related to each other, except on the similar name.

Its possible to use a `.properties` file on the Node driver, too. But in this case, we need to pass a filename to `SentryCliPlugin` where to find the config like this:

```
new SentryCliPlugin({
 release: process.env.LAST_BUILD_TIME,
 configFile: process.env.SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE,
 include: './app/dist',
 configFile: 'sentry.properties'
})
```

But keep in mind, that your need to provide url, organisation and a way of authentication like auth-token as well in your `sentry.properties` file:

```
defaults.url=http://SentryHost:9000
defaults.org=<YourOrganisationShortname>
defaults.project=<YourProjectShortname>
# Generate this on http://<SentryHost>:9000/api/
auth.token=xxx
```

The short names can be determined in the settings of Sentry as well as in the url.

Comment: They are related beacuse webpack requires node.js, and also I pass filename to `SentryCliPlugin `... My `.property` file is same as you mentioned in comment, and that's also stated in docs...

Comment: Little correction for `sentry.properties` file that you have mentioned in comment... I've updated question with example...

Comment: My statement regarding the relation was in relation of Java and JavaScript, cause I thought you mixed both of them (which I saw very often in the past). To your problem: Did you printed the value of `process.env.SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE` to see that it's correct? A few days ago, I got the same error than you. After providing the `properties` file and link to it using `configFile` it works fine. So I'd assume that something is wrong with our paths. Or your target files are in another directory which make the path invalid. I'd try an absolute path as well to exclude this.

Comment: Yes, I've printed that in `/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/index.js` and path is good. Path is absolute because I'm doing something like this `SENTRY_PROPERTIES_FILE="$(pwd)/sentry.properties"` in my bash script... I've opened also issue on github repo, but I wanted first to be sure that I'm not doing something really wrong :)